# Reference object inside a function, module export

Tags: javascript, node.js

**module1.js**

```
module.exports = function (input, input2) {

    var user = {

        email: function () {
            return "exp";
        }

    }

    return user;


}
```

**modulegetter.js**

```
var module1 = require('.../module1.js'); //correct path.

console.log(module1.user.email());
```

**Objective:** I want to refer to the email function inside of the user  var inside of the exported function, how do I do that?

**The code I have right now** does not work, I run it and get:

```
"Cannot read property 'email' of undefined"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be able to call the `email` method:

```
const module1 = require('module1.js');
module1(a, b).email();
```

The module exports a constructor function.  You have to call that constructor function and then when you call that function with `module1(a, b)`, you get back an object that has a `.email()` method on it.

You were apparently trying to do:

```
module1.user.email();
```

That has two separate things wrong with it.

1. You need to call the constructor function with `module1(a, b)`.  `module1` is just a function that has no properties in your implementation.  To get the user object, you have to call that function.
2. There is no `.user` property on the return object.  The return value from calling the constructor function is the whole user object so you just reference reference the `.email()` method directly on it.

Comment: Why do I not need a reference to `.user`, which contains the email() fn?

Comment: @Marodian - You are apparently under a misconception that local variables declared inside of functions are somehow accessible as properties of a function without executing that function.  That is not true at all in Javascript.  A local variable is not accessible at all outside a function,  The way you've declared your module, all it exports is a function.  To get the `user` object, you have to EXECUTE that function.  Then, that function returns an object which has a `.email` property on it.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting functions is '*advanced*' use of the
`module.exports` system. Think of it this way:

1.

simple **module** that exports a literal value [*easy peasy*]:

```
// file1.js
module.exports = 12;

// file2.js
var x = require('file1.js');
console.log(x); // 12
```

2.

a **module** that exports a function [*does nothing before invoked*]:

```
// file3.js
module.exports = function () {
    console.log('somebody run me');
}

// file4.js
var x = require('file3.js');
console.log(x); // oops a [function]
// ... but
console.log(x()); // yay; somebody run me
```

3.

a **module** that exports an invoked function [*easier for end user*]:

```
// file5.js
module.exports = function () {
    console.log('somebody run me, now');
}();

// file5.js
var x = require('file5.js');
console.log(x); // somebody run me, now
```

4.

finally, a **module** that exports an invokable function, in need of
   arguments [*more complex, but more flexible*]:

```
// file6.js
module.exports function (foo) {
   return "foo-" + foo;
};

// file7.js
var x = require('file6.js');
var result = x('something');
console.log(result); // foo-something
```